# How to concatenate a space in php

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

So how exactly do i add a space in between $book and the parenthesis ?

```
<?php foreach($books as $isbn => $book) { ?>
<li><?php echo $book . "(" . $isbn . ")"; ?></li>
```

what i get is clearly $book($isbn), and what i want is $book ($isbn)

do i need to add

```
. " " .
```

between my concatenated variable and 1st parenthesis ?

```
<li><?php echo $book . " " . "(" . $isbn . ")"; ?></li> ?
```

please help i cant seem to get it to work, thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? What exactly isn't working with that last line of code you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<li><?php echo $book . " (" . $isbn . ")"; ?></li>
```